# Using Pyarrow to read parquet files written by Spark increases memory significantly

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyarrow

I am running into this issue where the memory usage of my container increases drastically when I try to read a parquet file. The parquet file was written using Spark and I am trying to read it using Pyarrow.

In this specific scenario, a 10mb parquet file becomes over 3gb in size. I am guessing the data types for some columns are given large memory reservations, but I do not know for sure.

Here is the code and some screenshots of what I am seeing:

**The code that writes the file(Scala 2.11, spark 2.2.1, (AWS Glue)):**

```
  def write(implicit spark: SparkSession, df: DataFrame, s3Bucket: String, s3Key: String, mode: String): Boolean ={
    df.write
      .mode(mode)
      .option("header", true)
      .parquet(s3Bucket + "/" + s3Key)

    true
  }
}
```

**The schema of the file once it's written:**

[image]

**The code that reads the file(pandas==0.25.2, pyarrow==0.15.1):**

```
@profile
def readParquet():
    srDf = pq.ParquetDataset('test.parquet').read().to_pandas()
    print(srDf.info(verbose=True))

readParquet()
```

**The output of memory_profiler:**

[image: memory profiler]

**The file itself:**

[image]

**The schema of the file after it is read:**

[image]

I am confused as to why the string columns are being inferred as object types in pyarrow. I believe that is what is causing all the memory increases. This is a small amount of data and I was hoping to process it in AWS lambda, but lambda has a 3gb memory limitation so I am unable to read the file there. I looked into try to explicitly define a schema for pyarrow to read the parquet file as but I couldn't seem to get that to work. It doesn't look like it's supported unless I have overlooked something. Please let me know if you guys see an obvious error in my implementation. Thank you.

Comment: What is the size of the uncompressed data according to parquet-tools?  You might also try checking the size/schema when read directly into an [arrow table](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#reading-and-writing-single-files) might also be a good point of comparison.

Comment: Uncompressed the file is 46mb, once read in arrow, it takes up 3.6 gig

Comment: Unusually, doing this read using fastparquet lowers the memory usage down to 1gb from 3.4gb.

Comment: Can you split the reading with pyarrow (with `ParquetDataset.read()`) and the conversion to pandas (with `to_pandas()`) when measuring memory? It would be interesting to see which of the two steps is the bottleneck here.

Comment: Also, do you have many duplicated strings? In that case, you could try the  `strings_to_categorical=True`option in `to_pandas()`. Alternatively, if you don't want categorical dtype, passing `deduplicate_objects=True` could also help with with the string columns.

Comment: I split them and it was 2.7gb on the ```ParquetDataset.read())``` and ```to_pandas()``` added 800mb

Comment: The best place to collaborate further is probably the Apache Arrow JIRA or either the dev@ or user@ mailing list.

Comment: Obviously if you can share a file with us to help debug that would be very useful

Comment: I can't share the file unfortunately. I've switched to using spark to read in the files and it's using much less memory and processing much faster as expected.